# How to create a custom camera shutter animation (like in SocialCam app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to know how can I customize the 'iris' or 'shutter' animation of the iPhone's camera. An awesome example of what I am trying to achieve can be found in SocialCam app.

When you launch the camera, there's a custom iris effect as shown below:

[image]

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not customize the shutter, but simply create a new animation. You can do that using Core Animation.

Using core animation makes it simple to move views around using minimal programming.

Please read: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try these link , it consist of Project files too.[iPhone Camera Shutter Animation](http://www.juicybitssoftware.com/2009/08/31/iphone-camera-shutter-animation/)